# Cannot upload .blend through Blend Exchange

Tags: bug, status-completed, blend-exchange

I am trying to upload a `.blend` via Blend exchange. But after uploading, instead of getting a url to copy and paste, I am getting this. Any fixes?
[image: Instead of getting a url, i am getting a text <code><html></code> in red background]

Comment: Do note that blend-exchange is run by a member of our community and it is a private site separate from the SE network. Thus this is not the best place for bug reports about that site. On the bottom of the [help page](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/) it says to contact the site owner ([GiantCowFilms](http://blender.stackexchange.com/users/3127/giantcowfilms)), or open a github issue.

Comment: It was probably caused by the filesize. 10 MB shouldn't be a problem, but I recently reconfigured PHP, and the upload limit might not be correct. I will look into fixing this now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you so much for pointing this out, this issue affected a large number of other users.

The exact error, verbatim from the log:

> POST Content-Length of 12143120 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

What was happening (to ALOT of users it seems, based on my error log), is that the file, which is sent in the HTTP post request, was to big for the post request limit set by PHP in the PHP configuration.

I swear I had *expressly* set the value to be big enough, but apparently it didn't work.

It has now been fixed.

The learning takeaway for me has been to actually test if config values have been updated, since sometimes something goes wrong in writing the new config.

Sorry for any inconvenience this may have caused.

Comment: Did I thank you for your AWESOME .blend upload thing? [LOUD AND CLEAR] THANK YOU GiantCowFilms FOR WHAT YOU'RE GIVING TO US !!!! and thanks a lot also for [the HDRs](http://giantcowfilms.com/category/hdrs/) :)

Comment: @Bithur Thanks for the kind words :)

Comment: I just can't say how much you deserve my (our) thanks.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms - there seem to be errors during upload again, regardless of the file size. Again, many thanks for this awesome service!

Comment: @metaphor_set Rewrite coming soon. I'm hoping that we will a) not have this many issues, and b) I will know sooner (I actually have some kind of error reporting). Anyway, I think the issue was caused by either a mysql or a php upgrade that I did in preparation to launch the rewrite, and did not fully test. Now Fixed.